# Where do I have to go to find my promotional weapons?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've gotten as far as the citadel, and I haven't found my promotional weapons from playing the Kingdom of Amalur demo.

Where should I go to find my Chakram Launcher and Reckoner Knight armor?  If they should have been automatically added, how do I link my 2 EA accounts?

Just to round out the question, where is the other pre-order gear picked up from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chakram launcher should be available to you immediately. Once you find the first weapon bench you should be able to select it under the list of available assault rifles. Alternately, if you find a weapon during a mission, you can choose to change your loadout and equip the weapon that way.

If the weapon isn't showing up, it might be that it wasn't unlocked. In order to unlock the Chakram Launcher, you have to get to the end of the 45 minute timed segment of the Kingdomes of Amalur demo.

The Reckoner Knight armor should be available once you return to the Normandy after the Citadel section. If you go to the armory, there is an area that allows you to change your armor. The second slider down allows you to select the Reckoner armor.

Regarding your EA accounts, no additional linking should be necessary as long as you're playing with the same account/console that you played the demo on.

Comment: I hadn't gotten to the end of the 45 minutes.  I also needed to contact support to get things sorted out.

Answer (score 5):

From a [post on the Official Bioware Forums](http://social.bioware.com/forum/Mass-Effect-3/Mass-Effect-3-PC-Technical-Support/How-to-download-and-install-Chakram-Launcher-9621372-1.html):

> "Instructions for Single Player In-Game Item Requisition
>
> 1. Log in with the same account you used to redeem your code in Origin or with the account you used to access the BioWare Social Network
>      website.
> 2. Allow the DLC to download and install.
> 3. Run Mass Effect 3.
> 4. Start a new game or load an existing one.
> 5. The in-game items will be available once you gain access to the Normandy after completing the game’s prologue.
> 6. The items will appear on the Weapon Bench or in the Armor Locker located on the Normandy."

So you should find the weapon and the armor once you have access to the Normandy. Make sure that you're using the correct account and everything is working on that end.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the other suggestions work out (as they did not in my case) you have to contact EA customer support directly.

Once they look and see everything is legit, they are able to manually activate the promotional items.  I used Live Chat and everything was resolved in about 15 minutes.